# How can I change all the labels from the exsheets packages?

Tags: exam, exsheets, answers, questionnaire

I am using Exsheets package to do an exam

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
Question Here
\end{question}
 \begin{solution} 
Solution here
 \end{solution}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

But I don't want to label the questions as "Exercise" or the answers as "Solutions". I want the document to be like this.

1. Question Here
2. Solution here

and not

Question 1: Question here

Solution 1: Solution here

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To suppress the names you can use `\SetupExSheets{question/name={\hskip-1em},solution/name={\hskip-1em}}`. I put in a negative `\hskip` because `exsheets` puts a space between the name and the number, so this gets rid of it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{question/name={\hskip-1em},solution/name={\hskip-1em}}
\begin{document}

\begin{question}
Question Here
\end{question}
 \begin{solution}
Solution here
 \end{solution}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```